# error in script file line: 1 Unexpected token UNIQUE, requires COLLATION in statement [SET DATABASE UNIQUE]

Tags: eclipse, hsqldb

Whenever I connect to HSQLDB from my application deployed on eclipse Juno, it throws an exception as : 
 java.sql.SQLException: error in script file line: 1 Unexpected token UNIQUE, requires COLLATION in statement [SET DATABASE UNIQUE]

I have searched for the solution and the same problem was solved under JBoss 5.x, but I am not able to understand which version of hsqldb.jar I should replace the existing jar file with. I am working on CentOS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the latest version of HSQLDB jar, currently 2.2.9.

Your database files are version 2.x, but the jar you are using is probably 1.8.x or earlier. It is important to use the same jar version (major.minor).

Comment: Thanks fredt. My problem is solved. I have one more question. I have a method that takes a customer name as its argument and gives the entire data related to him. Now I should iterate through the result set and have my results written to a DataOutput object.How should I convert that object to type "Customers" as the method should return a variable of type "Customers" which is a predefined class. I need a method to convert DataOutput objects to a byte array atleast.

Comment: Please ask a new question regarding "Customers" and provide more details.

Comment: Ok, I will make it a little simple.I need a function to take a name and return the details of the record associated with that name.How do i do this? I have all the info. in my result set, but i need a way to pass it to one variable and return the value.

Comment: You must ask a separate question, as this is not related to your original question.